# Nexenta bash script uses /usr/sun/bin/sed instead of /usr/bin/sed

Tags: sed, solaris, nexenta

I'm using a script for Linux and for Solaris (Nexenta).

This line works on Linux, but not on solaris (but when run from shell it works):

```
cat "pg_hba.conf" | sed "0,/^local/{s/md5/trust/}"
```

The error message is:

```
sed: command garbled: 0,/^local/{s/md5/trust/}
```

After some research, I found out that the `sed` that bash uses in the script is different.

from shell: `/usr/bin/sed`

from script: `/usr/sun/bin/sed`

I want to make the script use `/usr/bin/sed`.

What I tried to do:

1. call `sed` with full path. Same results. It seems that it is still uses the other `sed`...
2. tried to call it via `bash -l`. Same results.
3. tried to declare a different command: `S=/usr/lib/sed` and use `$S` instead. Same results.
4. checked PATH - both cmd and script have `/usr/bin` in it.
5. Tried replacing the double quotes to single. Same results.
6. tried running the sed with -r flag. Output is :

   `# /usr/xpg4/bin/sed -r
    /usr/xpg4/bin/sed: illegal option -- r
    Usage:  sed [-n] script [file...]
            sed [-n] [-e script]...[-f script_file]...[file...]`

HELP??

What I need to do is to replace the first match of "md5" with "trust" on the first line that starts with "local"). I know I can do it otherwise but I the `sed` issue is itching me too much!

## EDIT:

I hope this makes a little order...

1. PATH from login shell = `/usr/local/ctera/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/ctera/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin`
2. PATH from script =
   `/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/ctera/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin:/usr/local/ctera/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin`
3. PATH from script when `PATH=$(command -p getconf PATH):$PATH` is called = 
   `/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/SUNWspro/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/SUNWspro/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/ctera/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin:/usr/local/ctera/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin`
4. `truss -f sed` from login shell calls `/usr/bin/sed`
5. `truss -f sed` from script calls `/usr/sun/bin/sed`
6. `truss -f /usr/bin/sed` from script calls `/usr/sun/bin/sed` !!!
7. After setting `PATH=$(command -p getconf PATH):$PATH`:
   7.1 `truss -f sed` from script calls `/usr/xpg4/bin/sed`
   7.2 `truss -f /usr/bin/sed` from script calls `/usr/sun/bin/sed` !!!

## MORE INFO:

Commands output: (run both from shell prompt and from within the script)

1. `truss -ft execve  /usr/bin/sed q`
   as shell command:
    `8604:   execve("/usr/bin/sed", 0x08047D20, 0x08047D2C)  argc = 2`
   from script:
   `8545:   execve("/usr/sun/bin/sed", 0x08047768, 0x08047774)  argc = 2`
2. `file /usr/bin/sed`
   as shell command:
   `/usr/bin/sed: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped`
   from script:
   `file: /usr/bin/sed zero size or zero entry ELF section - ELF capabilities ignored
   file: /usr/bin/sed: can't read ELF header
   /usr/bin/sed:   data`
3. `ls -l /usr/bin/sed`
   as shell command:
   `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 96440 May 31  2008 /usr/bin/sed`
   from script:
   `-rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root       96440 May 31  2008 /usr/bin/sed`
4. `ls -ld $(type -pa sed)`
   as shell command:
   `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 96440 May 31  2008 /bin/sed
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 96440 May 31  2008 /usr/bin/sed`
   from script:
   `-rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root       96440 May 31  2008 /usr/bin/sed`
5. `md5sum $(type -pa sed)`
   as shell command:
   `385361c5111226c8eac8e25b53fed29c  /bin/sed
   385361c5111226c8eac8e25b53fed29c  /usr/bin/sed`
   from script:
   `385361c5111226c8eac8e25b53fed29c  /usr/bin/sed`

   - The script is invoced by JAVA code.
   - `uname -a`
     `SunOS cteraportal 5.11 NexentaOS_134f i86pc i386 i86pc Solaris`
   - This might add info about the `sed` version on my machine

     ```
     ~# ll `find / -name sed`  
     -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 96440 May 31  2008 /usr/bin/sed  
     -r-xr-xr-x 1 root bin  35656 Sep  7  2010 /usr/sun/bin/sed  
     -r-xr-xr-x 1 root bin  32104 Sep  7  2010 /usr/ucb/sed  
     -r-xr-xr-x 1 root bin  35636 Sep  7  2010 /usr/xpg4/bin/sed  

     /usr/share/doc/sed:  
     total 113  
     -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   168 Jun 21  2005 AUTHORS.gz  
     -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2507 Jun 21  2005 BUGS.gz  
     -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6584 Feb  3  2006 NEWS.gz  
     -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   285 Jun 21  2005 README.gz  
     -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1071 Jan 12  2006 THANKS.gz  
     -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4806 May 31  2008 changelog.Debian.gz  
     -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 32312 Feb  3  2006 changelog.gz  
     -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   796 May 31  2008 copyright  
     drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     3 May 30  2011 examples  
     drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     3 May 30  2011 sed-4.1.5  
     -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 56538 May 31  2008 sedfaq.txt.gz
     ```

Comment: Your `sed` command may be syntactically incorrect. Usually when you call `sed` it would be followed by a flag. For example: `sed 's/cat/dog/g'`

Comment: But works when run from cmd

Comment: Can you try replacing the double quotes with single quotes? I'm guessing that syntax may have something to do with this, but im not a 100%.

Comment: Tried that as well :) Same results... I'll edit my post with this suggestion included

Comment: May I ask what the `0,` is supposed to do?

Comment: It searches all the lines from the first until ^local is found

Comment: What do you mean by _from cmd_? Are you saying that `/usr/lib/sed '0,/^local/{s/trust/md5/}'` works at the shell prompt, but not in a script?

Comment: yes, that's what i meant

Comment: What is the value of the `PATH` environment variable? It's not enough to know that `/usr/bin` is on it, it matters what else is there and in what order. Are you sure you have a `/usr/lib/sed`? That's highly unusual. And what's this about `illigal option` — did you copy-paste that or did you mis-type it? Always copy-paste.

Comment: I edited the post, I think it answers all the questions

Comment: Can you post the exact output of `truss -ft execve  /usr/bin/sed q`, of `file /usr/bin/sed`, of `ls -l /usr/bin/sed`. of `type -a sed`? , of `ls -ld $(type -a sed)` and of `md5sum $(type -a sed)`?

Comment: Sorry, meant `$(type -pa sed)` above (assuming `bash` is the shell).

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas, do you want the output of the commands run as shell commands, or inside the script?

Comment: At least at the shell prompt, both if you can. I can trim it to keep only the interesting parts if you wish.

Comment: Got both in the edited post. This is very interesting. In the script it acts as if there is no different sed from the one run from shell, but it actually uses the Solaris version...

Comment: Is your script run in a different Solaris zone? How is it invoked? Can you upload your `/usr/bin/sed` somewhere? What version of Nexenta is it? I don't understand how `truss /usr/bin/sed` can not show `execve("/usr/bin/sed",...)`

Comment: See another edit of the post :) That's what this post about. How is it possible that a different `sed` is called... The same problematic sed replacement works via shell prompt. So there is a "good" sed on my system, which is the `/usr/bin/sed`, that just isn't called in the script. Some magic going on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, found it. That now makes sense.

the behaviour is Nexenta-specific and explained at http://lwn.net/Articles/334756/

> #### GNU and not GNU
>
> The default behavior of Nexenta is to prefer GNU utilities, which are installed in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin` and so on. The Sun versions of these utilities are installed in `/usr/sun/bin` and `/usr/sun/sbin`. Nexenta uses a trick to be able to switch between a GNU and a SUN personality: if the environment variable SUN_PERSONALITY is set to one, the search paths `/usr/sun/bin` and `/usr/sun/sbin` take preference, even if the user executes the commands explicitly by their absolute path, e.g. `/usr/bin/sed`. This ensures that Solaris-based scripts work in Nexenta without modifications. Nexenta also uses this functionality in its SVR4 package commands. They can be used to install native Solaris packages in SVR4 format, calling alien to convert the package on-the-fly to a Debian package.

That's done somewhere in the libc.

So,

```
$ sed --version
GNU sed version 4.1.5
Copyright (C) 2003 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE,
to the extent permitted by law.
$ SUN_PERSONALITY=1 sed --version
sed: illegal option -- version
```

So, your script started from Java, must have the SUN_PERSONALITY set.

You can unset that in your script if you want the GNU tools.

Comment: I had similar suspicions about the *POSIXLY_CORRECT* and or *--posix* switches and GNU `sed`'s behavior in their presence, but came up dry in tests and gave up. Still - I did learn about this command: `sed v`
     *...does nothing... but `sed` fails if GNU `sed` extensions are not supported... because other `sed`s do not implement it. ...you can specify the version...  required, such as `4.0.5`. The default is `4.0`...`v`
 enables all GNU extensions even if `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is set in the environment.*

Comment: `unset SUN_PERSONALITY` works, but messes other things up, as I apparently rely on SUN functionality in other stuff. So I `unset` and `export` it back to 1, and everything works. THANKS!

Comment: @csny, I would use POSIX syntax in your script. Both Sun (at least after `PATH=$(getconf PATH):$PATH`) and Gnu should be mostly POSIX compatible.

Comment: To anyone who reads this: Just wanted to point out that `SUN_PERSONALITY` is a Nexenta invention, not something that exists in Solaris as such.

Comment: @nolan6000, I agree it should be pointed out. I've updated my answer to make it clearer and changed the title of the question s/Solaris/Nexenta/

Answer (score 2):

In any case,

```
sed "0,/^local/{s/md5/trust/}"
```

Is GNU specific (the `0` address and the missing `;` before `}`) and won't work with any other `sed` implementation (and Solaris doesn't ship with GNU `sed` by default).

Portably/standardly:

```
sed '/^local/,$!s/md5/trust/'
```

to replace only on the lines up to (but not included) the  first one starting with `local`. Or:

```
awk 'NR == 1, /^local/ {gsub(/md5/,"trust")}; {print}'
```

(on Solaris, you may need `command -p awk`).

If you want the substitution on the first line that matches `/^local/`:

```
awk '/^local/ && ! seen {gsub(/md5/, "trust"); seen = 1}; {print}'
```

Or:

```
sed -e '/^local/!b' -e 's/md5/trust/g;:1' -e 'n;b1'
```

To be sure to get POSIX compliant utilities in both Solaris and Linux (from a POSIX shell like `bash` or `ksh` (or `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` on Solaris)), you can add:

```
PATH=$(command -p getconf PATH):$PATH
```

to the top of the script. Or add `command -p` in front of every command which you want the POSIX version of.

Comment: Thanks for the help, `sed -e '/^local/!b' -e 's/md5/trust/g;:1' -e 'n;b1'` works well. But I still want to understand why wouldn't the GNU compatible line work in the script, but works from shell.
And why I can't make it use `/usr/lib/sed`...

Comment: @csny, does `/usr/lib/sed --version` work and mention it's GNU? Does `truss -f /usr/lib/sed` shows it eventually executing another `sed` somewhere? (like /usr/lib/sed being a wrapper that calls this or that sed based on the environment)? Is /usr/lib/sed a script?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `/usr/bin/sed`...

Comment: The version is: GNU sed version 4.1.5

Comment: I added truss -f sed to the script and it does show that it isn't `/usr/bin/sed`, but it is `/usr/xpg4/bin/sed`.

Comment: I edited the post, I think it answers all the questions

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - do you think maybe this guy is running a `csh` script accidentally - like in your `which which` question/answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another portable way to do it with `sed`:

```
sed 1i\\ file |
sed '1,/^local/s/md5/trust/;1d'
```

Just give yourself a little breathing room. That inserts a blank line at the head of the file so you can rely upon a thing or two.

You might also do:

```
{ echo; cat file; } |
sed '1,/^local/s/md5/trust/;1d'
```

Comment: Thanks, I already have a workaround for this, but I still can't understand why isn't the script acting like the shell prompt, when calling `sed`...

Comment: @csny - Did you try `command -V sed` at the prompt and in a script/non-interactive shell? Maybe `alias | grep sed=` also from the interactive shell?

Comment: maybe also `readlink /usr/bin/sed`

Comment: Wait... @csny - is there a shebang line in that script? At the top? Is the shell that is executing that script definitely `bash`? What happens when you do `lsof "$0"` while in the script?

Comment: `#!/bin/bash` is at the top. the shell is bash as well. There is no  `lsof` on my Nexenta, but the output of `ps -ef` include this: `root  4949  4498   0 08:23:39 ?           0:00 /bin/bash /usr/local/ctera/bin/ctera.sh initdb`.  No aliases, and no `readlink`... `command -V sed` results in `/usr/bin/sed`.

Comment: @csny You're root in the script or you're root at the prompt? Seriously - this is weird. What do you get with `printf %s\\n '#!/usr/bin/sed' '0,/^local/{s/md5/trust/}' > ~/sedscript; chmod +x ~/sedscript; ~/sedscript`? Can you watch that with `ps`?

Comment: I'm always root. JAVA is run as root, and calls this script. But do you think that `/usr/bin/sed` has permission limitations..? I added to the bottom of the post the long list out put of all the `sed` that exist on my system

Comment: @csny -I don't think so. I think I was on the wrong track. I think Stephane got to the bottom of this one already, have you seen his new answer yet?